# google oauth request callback return "http://mysite.com/callback#access_token=xxx" instead of "http://mysite.com/callback?access_token=xxx"

Tags: oauth, gmail

I'm writing a website which need get user contacts.

I use gmail oauth, and follow the step here: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html

everything works fine except the callback, I set callback to :

```
http://mysite.com/callback
```

and google gives me:

```
http://mysite.com/callback#access_token=xxx
```

which I need is

```
http://mysite.com/callback&access_token=xxx
```

is there something I don't know? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For web applications, you need to request a **code**, and not a **token**; for this, set `request_type=code` in your authorization url, as described here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#responsetypeparameter
and here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#handlingresponse